# Regex Artist-Title

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have quite a long list of artists combined with a song of them.
A few examples are listed below:

```
30 Seconds To Mars - Savior
3-nen E-Gumi Utatan - Seishun Satsubatsuron (TV)
7!! - Start Line (TV)
ABBA - Estoy soñando
AKINO with bless4 - Kimi no Shinwa ~ Aquarion Dai Ni Shou (TV)
µ's - Angelic Angel (TV)
```

Every name is formated like this list i've tried to add all the possible combinations.

I need a list of all the artists and songs seperated.
How would i extract the Artist so i can copy that to another file.
And how would i extract the song so i can copy it to another file.

As said the format is Artist - Song

i have tried this regex atm: `^.*(-)`
But this selects the - signs too

Comment: In your second one - what if you have a song title with `-` in it?  how do you differentiate between one and the other?

Comment: If the the sentence would be: `test - pizza - test` The output should be `pizza - test`. So i think it should look at the first dash (-) with spaces around it.

Comment: Duplicate your file for the artist and songlist - in both use `^(.*?) - (.*)` as searc pattern, in the first replace with `\1`, in the second replace with `\2`

Comment: Try "^(.*?) - " to keep songs and " - .*" to get artists (replace with empty string in both cases)

Comment: If the artist is extracted removing the first characters (spaces and dashes) until the first character comes should give me the song title

Comment: May i know where there's a min vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(.*?)\s-\s(.*?)$
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cC5yP6/1)

Comment: Note that this doesn't guarantee *which* hyphen it'll split on (if a song title has a hyphen with spaces surrounding). Regex internals probably always make it the last, though. Otherwise you could change it to `^(.*?)\s-\s([^-]?)$`. That should guarantee it's the last.

Comment: @ClasG You can control whether it takes the first or last by using a ? in only one of the capture groups. Besides that, well, that's _always_ a limitation.

Comment: @Nyerguds True. That's another way of solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem hard; you just have to include the spaces in your regex, either as literals or as the regex `\s`.

Also, your capture group in your regex is around the - sign. I assume you need to capture the artist and title instead.

`^(.*?)\s+-\s+(.*?)$`

Then just replace using `\1` for the artist and `\2` for the title.

As for exactly what you want to do... simply make two copies of the file, and replace by `\1` in one copy for the artists and by `\2` in the other for the titles.

Answer (score 0):

This regex `.+(?=-)` will get everything up to the last hyphen. `(?!<-)[^-]+$` everything after it.

Check [this example](https://regex101.com/r/uH8gP9/2) that combines the two and gets song in capture group 1 and artist in number 2.

Regards.

Comment: There's not really a guarantee the song title won't contain hyphens. The only constant seems to be that the separator is the literal "space, hyphen, space".

Comment: Yeah, but this works *up to*, and *from* the **last** hyphen. So... It'll work :)

Comment: Still doesn't match the format of a hyphen surrounded by spaces provided by the question, though. It fails from the moment a song title contains a hyphen. It's just the wrong criterion.

Comment: @Nyerguds Don't quite follow... Have you checked the example provided in the answer [and here](https://regex101.com/r/uH8gP9/2).

Comment: Open that link you just posted and put a dash in any of the title names. Really. Just replace the title "Start Line (TV)" by "Start-Line (TV)". _It'll break._